# Configuring HKEY_CURRENT_USER with DSC Resource actually updates HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT

Tags: dsc, powershell-dsc

The following DSC declaration writes to Registry key  HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Console instead of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console.  Why?

```
Registry ConsoleFaceName
{
  Key         = 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console'
  ValueName   = "FaceName"
  ValueData   = "Lucida Console"
  Ensure      = "Present"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of writing to `.DEFAULT` is because the DSC Local Configuration Manager (LCM) is running as local system, which does not have a current user registry hive.

If you want it to update a particular user you need to run using [`PsDscRunAsCredential` (docs linked)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/configdatacredentials#handling-credentials-in-dsc), where `$Credential` is the credentials from the user you want to change the value for.

```
Registry ConsoleFaceName
{
  Key                   = 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console'
  ValueName             = "FaceName"
  ValueData             = "Lucida Console"
  Ensure                = "Present"
  PsDscRunAsCredential  = $Credential
}
```

Before doing this please read [Securing the MOF File.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/securemof)