# Configuring HKEY_CURRENT_USER for all Users with DSC

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'd like to overwrite an existing registry key in HKCU for all users on this device with Desired State Configuration.

I already found, that I could use the users credentials([Configuring HKEY_CURRENT_USER with DSC Resource actually updates HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124923/configuring-hkey-current-user-with-dsc-resource-actually-updates-hkey-users-def)), but I do not have them.

Any ideas?

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is just an alias for the appropriate subkey in `HKEY_USERS`, depending on who's logged into the session. If you want to change something for all users, just go through all subkeys of `HKEY_USERS`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Your last statement is potentially misleading. HKEY_USERS would only have _loaded_ hives. So if there was a user not signed in that needed the change it would not find them.

Comment: @Matt: which makes the conclusion, I guess, "use Group Policy instead". Because you probably don't want to deal with things like roaming profiles of users not currently logged in... at least not with DSC.

Comment: @JeroenMostert GPO would be the way to go yes.

Comment: Just chiming in: registry edits for all users should not be handled by DSC/Scripts unless done through login scripts or GPO.  Otherwise you run into very obscure issues (as it's not done very often, for good reason)

Answer (score 0):

Technically if your administrator on the Box you can still do this,
Load their Registery Hive and Change a Key.

```
$Username = "TestUser"
reg load hku\$Username C:\Users\$Username\NTUSER.DAT
New-PSDrive -Name $Username -PSProvider Registry -Root HKU\$Username
Set-Location "$($Username):\Control Panel\desktop\colors"
Get-ItemProperty -Path. -Name ActiveBorder
Set-ItemProperty -Path. -Name ActiveBorder -Value "218 208 200"
Get-ItemProperty -Path. -Name ActiveBorder
Remove-PSDrive -Name $Username -Force
```

Comment: This has the potential problem of locking a user out depending on if their registry is loaded.